# Show that $F(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{2x}{(2-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(1-2^{-n})x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, summation, power-series, generating-functions

> I've been working on a recent exercise question where I was asked to show that:
>   $$F(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{2x}{(2-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(1-2^{-n})x^n$$

Now I cansee that the infinite sum is a power series, which leads me to believe that I might argue that the Taylor series of a function *is* the power series for that function and then simply show that the taylor series for F(x) can be written as the sum seen on the far right. Now I've been able to show that the first term of the taylor series evaluated at x=0 is equivalent to the factor of the $x^1$ part of the infinite sum, but I'm confused as to how to go on from here.

I thought perhaps I might try to do some proof by induction, but that would require a generalized expression for the derivative of F(x) which doesn't exactly seem trivial.

I'd really appreciate some help as this has been puzzling me for hours.

Comment: Are you confused about how to find the taylor series?

Comment: I am not confused about how to find the taylor series, I'm unsure on how to prove that the taylor series ends up as the infinite sum on the right when evaluated at x=0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $|x|<1$, then$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n=\frac x{(1-x)^2}.$$Therefore, if $|x|<2$,$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\left(\frac x2\right)^n=\frac{x/2}{(1-x/2)^2}=2\frac x{(2-x)^2}.$$In other words,$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n2^{-n}x^n=\frac{2x}{(1-x)^2}.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: I can see the result from what you wrote, but I'm curious as to how you arrive at the first infinite sum you use.

Comment: We have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=\frac1{1-x}$ and therefore$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\right)'=\frac1{(1-x)^2}.$$So,$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n=\frac x{(1-x)^2}.$$